# Deleting columns with less than 6 decimals in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, decimal

I have a dataframe where some of the columns contain floating point numbers with 6 decimals but some columns only have 1 or 2 decimals. I want to delete all columns with less than 6 decimals. I tried filling the columns with less than 6 decimals but this did not turn out well.

Comment: Please read [`How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
import pandas as pd
data_preprocessed1 = pd.DataFrame({ "Value":[2675.39881,62.2320980,9.3409093,3.343434443],
                               "Landed weight":[10.0,5.0,10.0,10.10 ],
                               "Extra": [3.5728, 3.8263, 3.827264, 3.257]})
    

def delete_after_n_number(df,column,n):
    """
     Deleting column with less than 6 decimals in pandas

    delete all columns with less than 6 decimals

    Parameters
    ----------
    df : pd.DataFrame 
        initial dataframe 
    column : str
        name of the column you to check 
    n : int
        Deleting columns with less than n decimals in pandas

    Returns
    -------
    dataframe : pd.DataFrame
       dataframe wanted

    """
    lst_col=df.columns.to_list()
    df['copy'] = df[column].astype(str)
    df['count']=[len(val) for val in df['copy'].str.split('.',n=1,expand=True)[1]]
    verif=df.loc[df['count']<n,:].copy()
    if verif.shape[0]>0:
        lst_col.remove(column)
        df=df[lst_col].copy()
        print(lst_col)
    else :
        df=df[lst_col].copy()
        print(lst_col)
    return df

for col in data_preprocessed1.select_dtypes(include=[np.float64]).columns : 
    data_preprocessed1=delete_after_n_number(data_preprocessed1,col,6)
data_preprocessed1
```

Input :

[image]

Ouput :

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244785/discussion-on-answer-by-datascirookie-deleting-columns-with-less-than-6-decimals).